# How can I read a web content without selenium with python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to read if an element of a web page changes when I input some string of numbers in an input box. Is there a way to know the response of the web without having to open the web page in a tab with selenium? I am trying to check millions of inputs so it would be better to not have to open the tab and input each combination in the simulated selenium browser. Thanks.

Comment: Write your own web browser, or at least enough of one to address this particular task.

Comment: @ScottHunter And how do I do that? It seems very complicated

Comment: How complicated it is depends on how much of a browser's functionality you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using the --headless option that does not open a tab.

An example could be:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

browser.get("https://example.com")

print(browser.page_source)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks and I assume this consumes much less resources than the nomral mode right?

Comment: Yes. Indeed. If you do a random google, you will find out headless provide 2x to 15x faster performance that regular browser. But if the webpage which you are trying on allows scraping then do check if `beautifulsoup4` package solves your problem, which don't need browser at all.